# Are static induction and dynamic (motional) induction same phenomenon?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Whenever magnetic flux linked with a coil changes, voltage is induced in it. This is Faraday's law. Instead, if a conductor (no need of a coil) moves in a uniform magnetic field, voltage is induced across it due to Lorentz force. If one connects the two ends of the conductor across a resistance current will flow. Are the two phenomenon same? Will there be eddy currents induced in the conductor in the second case, when the circuit is open?

Comment: What do you mean by _two phenomenon same_? In both the cases $\boldsymbol \nabla\times \mathbf E = -~\partial_t \mathbf B$ is valid; the relation is "independent of the motion of the medium inside the field".

Comment: Is Faraday's law applicable to closed paths only? or, will changing magnetic field associated with a conductor which is not a loop induce voltage in it?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Note that in the second case, when the circuit is open, $\frac{\delta B}{\delta t}$ is zero, so no voltage should be induced.